# Enabling AspectJ for a Quartz Scheduler Job

Tags: spring

I have created bean which will be executed by a simple trigger quartz scheduler. When I enable AspectJ within my spring-context.xml , my scheduler job is not getting triggered

Here is a snippet of my spring-context.xml

```html
<!-- Scheduler Factory -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  <property name="triggers">
   <list>    
    <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Trigger  -->
 <bean id="simpleTrigger"
  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJobDetail" />
  <!-- 30 seconds -->
  <property name="startDelay" value="10000" />
  <!-- repeat every 50 seconds -->
  <property name="repeatInterval" value="10000" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Job Details -->
 <bean name="myJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  <property name="jobClass" value="test.MyJob" />
  <property name="jobDataAsMap">
   <map>
    .....
   </map>
  </property>
 </bean>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
....
```

I am not an expert in spring or aop. Can someone please explain what is wrong and how can we achieve it?
Without enabling AspectJ my scheduler gets triggered properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any aspects applied to the MyJob bean? If so, perhaps the aop mechanism creates a jdk dynamic proxy that cannot be recognised by the quartz api where you specify a specific job class of type MyJob. If this assumption is correct, then try:

```
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

That will instead use a CGLIB-based class proxy based on MyJob class.

I recommend reading http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying in order to understand any implications that each proxying mechanism may have.

If that was the problem, it may be better to avoid completely having an aspect around the job class itself, and perhaps putting it around a bean that the job class will call to perform the desired functionality

Comment: I have an aspect in one of the bean that will be called from MyJob and I had that bean class as final class, so CGLIB was unable to create a proxy. Now I have modified my bean to remove 'final' and got it working now. Thanks.